# Any idea why the method failed to validate?

Tags: java, servlets

Any idea why the isValidPassword() method is not performing the validation. Even though if the password length is less than 6 or password has the special characters failed to validate.

```
if(!SoccerUtils.isValidPassword(password)){
    out.print("<p style=\"color:red\">Password must be at least 6 characters long</p>");               
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("register.jsp");
    rd.include(request, response);              
    } else{          
        //Do some action here        
        }
```

Here I am calling the 'isValidPassword()' method, in this method I am checking two conditions (a) if the password length is less than 6 
then return false, else true. 
Similarly (b) if the 'password' doesn't have letter or Digit return false, else return true. Both cases are not validating. Can I have one return for both cases in the isValidPassword()?

```
public static boolean isValidPassword(String password) {        
        if (password.length()< 6  ) {
            return false;
        }

        for(int i=0; i<password.length(); i++) {
            if(!Character.isLetterOrDigit((password.charAt(i)))) {
                return false;
            }

        }

        return true;
}
```

Comment: inside your loop it will return false if they have a password containing special characters (in other words, not a letter or digit) Is this intended?

Example: Password123 is valid, but Password123! would be invalid.

Comment: What do you mean not validating? Add some data that you are trying to test with and what is the outcome vs expected outcome.

Comment: Yes emsimson92, this is intended. At the moment password is intended to have letter and numbers only.

Comment: So what is an example password you're using for validation?

Comment: example password is : abc1!

Comment: the ! in abc1! causes your 2nd if statement to become true and returns false. Instead, try using abc1 for a password or modifying the logic in your for loop.

Comment: Expected password should accept: test123, test1234, abcdef, 1234567

Comment: When debugging, can you see the value of password.length() in isValidPassword()  ?

Comment: It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger. Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: Yes, emsimson92 I have tried password = 12!@# and system still saving the Register data into database. Ideally It should not allow to save the data.

Comment: ??? Now you're coming up with a database. What has that to do with your question? Didn't emsimpson92's first comment provide a good explanation already?

Comment: To answer the title question directly: `isValidPassword` **isn't** failing to validate.  It **correctly** returns `false` if given the invalid password `12!@#`.  The code that is calling `isValidPassword` is failing to act correctly on the information returned by `isValidPassword`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Similarly (b) if the 'password' doesn't have letter or Digit return false, else return true.

What you are checking is different to what this requirement<sup>1</sup> states.  Your code is actually checking that **all** characters are either a letter or a number.

To understand what you code is doing, I suggest you either "hand execute" it, or use a debugger to watch what it is doing.

Try it with this example: "Passw0rd!", which (by my reading of the requirements) should be a valid password.  (Its length is > 6, and it contains a letter and a digit.)

---

> Can I have one return for both cases in the isValidPassword()?

You could ... but it will make the code more complicated!

---

<sup>1 - I suspect that you have copied that requirement incorrectly.  The requirement (b) is grammatically incorrect.  That grammatical error introduces an ambiguity in what the sentence actually means ... in English.</sup>